# how can i use scrapy to finish a distributed scraper with celery?

Tags: celery, scrapy

Now i want to complete a distributed scraper with scrapy and celery,my current idea is to use master-slave method,can someone tell me is that a good idea?is there a good open-source project for this?

Answer (score 2):

When i implemented a distributed crawling set-up.I achieved that with the help of redis. Here is how i did it.

I have a list of domains to be crawled upon.I will upload those domains to redis.In my project, i had 30K domains to scrape data from.

Use redis-py client to talk to redis, and feed the each url to scrapy.

Comment: but when you implement a distributed crawling set-up,you need to monitor all the client's status,and when you crawl once,you need check  every domail whether changes,so i think all the domains in memory is better,now i want to rewrite the scrapy with redis,and the master only analysis one website and then pick up all detail pages,then the master distribute the detail pages to slave,the slave complete the scrapy, save and report the crawl status.when check,the master just compare all the url to the cache,if changed then crawl again.